# allow only one checkbox ticked at a time android

Tags: java, android

I am using preference screen in layout.. However when I can tick all boxes at once.. How can I have it so only 1 box is ticked at a time..

```
  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="colour_white"
    android:title="White"

    android:defaultValue="true" />

     <CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="colour_red"
    android:title="Red"


     />
```

Comment: Would a radio button be more appropriate for your use case?

Comment: add android:dependency:"KEY_OF_PARENT" to childs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control it in java. Handle `CheckBoxPreference` click event and uncheck all checkboxes except one which has been fired the click event.

```
CheckBoxPreference cbp_white = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("colour_white");
CheckBoxPreference cbp_red = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("colour_red");

cbp_white.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
               //write your logic here
                //Example: cbp_red.setChecked(false);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Similarly handle change event of other checkboxes.

Comment: I tried this but failed I did.. 'colour_white.setChecked(false);' .. Didn't work, How can I handle CheckBoxPreference properly, can you please give me more information??

Answer (score 2):

You should use radio buttons and radio groups. Check boxes are *meant* to be multi select.